# "Hayom yom X b'shabas" or "bashabas"?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, prayer-book, pronunciation, nuschaot

A *sidur* I used this morning had the introductory line of the *[shir shel yom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shir_shel_yom)* as "hayom yom sheni **b'**shabas". When I checked the two *sidurim* I trust the most for excatitude in these matters, one had "**ba**shabas" and the other omitted the line completely. Which is the correct version?

Comment: Which two siddurim do you trust for the most exactitude in these matters, and which version comes from each siddur?

Comment: Checking my *siddurim*, I see only bashabbos, which I think is grammatically correct. Where do you find b'shabbos?

Comment: @jake It's a small promotional one from the Ateres publishing house called _T'filas Ya'akov M'shulam_.

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically speaking, the difference between **b'**-shabbos and **ba**-shabbos is that the the former contains just the "ב" prefix, while the latter is a contraction of both the "ב" and "ה" prefixes. So one would translate "**b'**-shabbos" as "of Shabbos" and "**ba**-shabbos" as "of *the* Shabbos".

That said, it would depend on what the intention is of the phrase "היום יום **__** בשבת".

Simply speaking, one could say that "שבת" in this context means "week". Indeed, the Metsudah siddur translates, "Today is the *_*_ day of the week." In this case, we need the "ה" prefix for "***the*** week", so the word becomes "**ba**-shabbos".

On the other hand, I found a Breslov siddur in my house that has a commentary with (typically) kabbalistic tendencies. In it, it quotes from Likutei Moharan (2:2) that everyday one should mention the Shabbos thereby extending its holiness through the entire week, and each day will have its own aspect of holiness, which is why we have a particular *mizmor* for each day.

According to this, it would seem that the phrase 
"היום יום __ בשבת" 
really means "Today is the **__** day of [the extended holiness of] Shabbos", in which case there is no need for the "ה" prefix, and the word will be "**b'**-shabbos". (The Breslov siddur indeed has "**b'**-shabbos".)

Comment: But then, consider the Hoshaana אום נצורה, where a number of lines end with בשבת or לשבת (referring to Shabbos itself, not to the week), and a cursory glance at a few siddurim shows that it's with patach in all of them. In that Breslov siddur, are these with sheva too?

Comment: @Alex, Didn't think of that. Unfortunately, the Breslov siddur is a weekday one, so I can't tell.

Comment: @Alex, Now I just found a siddur that's inconsistent. It has a sh'va for the daily *mizmor*, but a patach for אום נצורה. Maybe it's just a matter of style, whether to give an honorary "the" to read "the Shabbos".

Comment: Also, a quick search of Tanach shows that the proper form is "ba-Shabbos" or "la-Shabbos", and that sometimes "ha-Shabbos" is used over "Shabbos" and sometimes not.

Comment: Why does the "week" meaning require a definite article? Is it functioning there to indicate universal quantification (i.e. a reference to _every_ week and not just this one)?

Comment: @WAF, I'm not sure I get what you're trying to say. I think the intention is to say "today is such-and-such day of the week" as in "of *this* week". This requires a definite article. Just like we say "today is such-and-such day of *the* omer" -- "**ba** -omer".