# Meaning and usage of different names for Sunday

Tags: number, names, parashat-bereishit, ketubah

At the end of davening, when we introduce the daily psalm, for Sunday, we use the term  - יום **ראשוז** בשבת -  The **first** day in the week. (I'm translating the word שבת as "week", here. It's a valid translation, as my rav explained to me.)

However, in a *ketuvah* (marriage contract) or a *get* (divorce document) written on Sunday, we use the term **באחד** בשבת - On day **one** in the week.

I suspect that the use of the term אחד instead of ראשון is to emulate/allude to Genesis 1:5:

> וַיִּקְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים ׀ לָאוֹר֙ י֔וֹם וְלַחֹ֖שֶׁךְ קָ֣רָא לָ֑יְלָה וַֽיְהִי־עֶ֥רֶב וַֽיְהִי־בֹ֖קֶר י֥וֹם **אֶחָֽד**
>
> And God called the light Day, and the darkness He called Night. And
> there was evening and there was morning, **one day**.

What's the difference between the different contexts? Why in a *ketuvah* and *get* is the Torah term from Genesis for the 1st day אחד used, but in the daily psalm the more normal sounding term ראשון is used?

**Note:** I have used the example focusing only on the 1st day of the week, as this is the only place where we notice a term difference.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18878/759